# code coverage for js based electron application

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

I have a js based electron application which i have automated using selenium webdriver and testng. In the script i am using the chrome driver exe to open the electron application and automating the test cases.
Now i want to generate a code coverage report using my automation test suite written in java using selenium webdriver. How can i achieve the same, is there any tool or link which can help me in getting the code coverage for the electron application.

I am currently using istanbul to get the code coverage of the websites devloped using node js.

Thanks in advance!!